# WMTS - problem with serving

Tags: wms, qgis-server, wmts

I am trying to serve WMTS.
WMS works well - I can see different layers in QGIS.
I am using QGIS 3.26.

In Project Setting I choose: Enable Service Capabilities.
Then I use the following options:
[image]
In WMTS settings:
[image]

After sending files to server I can't see layers in WMTS in QGIS. For WMS all is fine.

What is wrong in serving WMTS?

[image]

I use this tutorial for serving WMTS:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/wms.html?highlight=serving%20wmts